# Is there an AASM method to get the next state if an event is fired without actually firing the event in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

I'm trying to build a flow diagram for `AASM`. I have a state machine with lots of states and lots of event for each state. It's difficult visualise the machine from the `AASM` state machine definition. To do this I'd like three methods as follows,

1) A method to return all states. This is already provided by `AASM`, i.e. `aasm.states.map(&:name)`

2) A method to return all events for a particular state. `AASM` already provides a method that returns all events from the current state, i.e. `aasm.events.map(&:name)`. This is almost what I want but I want to pass the state to the method. Rather than using the current state I want to use the state passed.

3) A method that excepts a state and an event. The method should return the next state when called, without actually changing anything in the state machine. Something like this,

```
next_1_1 = next_state(state1, event1)
next_1_2 = next_state(state1, event2)
next_1_3 = next_state(state1, event3)
next_2_4 = next_state(state2, event4)
next_2_5 = next_state(state2, event5)
next_2_6 = next_state(state2, event6)
```

Is anything like this available? Is there another way to implement what I want?

## Update

Based on @puneet18 answer, my state diagram would be as follows

```
State           Event       next state
----------------------------------------
:not_started    :start      :in_progress
:in_progress    :finish     :finished
                :reassign   :reassigned
:finished       :reassign   :reassigned
```

How would I generate a table like this with a block of code that will work for any state machine, no mater how complicated it is?